# I'm trying to change a color in OpenGL to white, but it keeps on switching back to black

Tags: java, opengl

```
    public void init(){
    if(!glfwInit()){

    }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height,"Flappy", NULL, NULL);
    if(window == NULL){
        return;
    }

    GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    glfwSetWindowPos(window, (vidmode.width() - width)/2, (vidmode.height() - height)/2);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, new Input());
    glfwShowWindow(window);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    GL.createCapabilities();
    GL11.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    System.out.println("OpenGL: " + GL11.glGetString(GL11.GL_VERSION));
```

I was trying to change the color to white with the GL11.glClearColor(1,1,1,1) but once I run the program, it just switches from white to black all the time until I shut it down.
I just want the color to stay white, thank you.

Comment: The code looks like a weird mix between C and Java, but it can't be both. Which one is it? Which language tag should be removed? And please refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: glfw by default uses double buffering. Probably just one buffer is "cleared white".

Comment: This is Java and LWJGL3, I found it today and I'm coding with a tutorial on youtube. The video is pretty old, and he has exactly the same code, just instead of GL.createCapabilities(), he uses GLContext.createFromCurrent()